# About the usage of the Green's function

Tags: electrostatics, boundary-conditions, greens-functions

This question is very basic, but I'm a little confused about this topic (I "learned" it during my bachelor's degree but never used it before).

I have an electrostatic problem described by the equation:
$$
\mathcal{O}_x\Phi(x)=4\pi f(x)
$$
where $\mathcal{O}_x$ is a linear differential operator, $\Phi(x)$ is the potential I want to find, and $f(x)$ is the source term.

The problem is defined in a piecewise domain given by $$\Omega=(-\infty,0]\cup[0,L]\cup[L,+\infty).$$ Furthermore, I define the Green's function of the problem as:
$$
\mathcal{O}_xG(x,x')=4\pi \delta(x-x')
$$
So, depending on the location of $x'$ (it is a dummy variable), I can express $G(x,x')$ as follows:
$$
G(x,x')= \left\{\begin{matrix}
g_1(x,x') & \text{if} & x'<0 \\
g_2(x,x') & \text{if} & 0<x'<L   \\
g_3(x,x') & \text{if} & x'>L  \\
\end{matrix}\right.
$$

From the above, it is clear that:
$$
\Phi(x)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx'G(x,x')f(x')
$$
And here is my question: I know that my source term is located within the interval $0<x<L$. Therefore, is the above integral the same as:
$$
\Phi(x)=\int_{-\infty}^0 dx'g_1(x,x')f(x')+\int_0^L dx'g_2(x,x')f(x')+\int_L^\infty dx'g_3(x,x')f(x')
$$
Or is it simply:
$$
\Phi(x)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx'g_2(x,x')f(x')
$$

I'm tempted to choose the second option based on the particular problem of a point-like source $f(x)=q\delta(x-a)$, where $0<a<L$. This would give me the electrostatic potential of a point-like charge inside the specified region, i.e., $qg_2(x,a)$.

I would appreciate any insights into this matter.

Comment: The way you write it, you are using intervals that are not even disjoint and your domain is just $\left(-\infty,\infty\right)$. Could you explain why you think you need the piecewise approach? Do you have some sort of boundary condition at $0$ and $L$?

Comment: @kricheli Yes, I have bounday conditions at $0$ and $L$ (basically discontinuity on the firts derivative), related to abrupte change of the permitivities.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$
\Phi(x)=\int_{-\infty}^0 dx'g_1(x,x')f(x')+\int_0^L dx'g_2(x,x')f(x')+\int_L^\infty dx'g_3(x,x')f(x')
$$
is correct just by definition of $G$ after inserting it into
$$
\Phi(x)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx'G(x,x')f(x')\,.
$$
In the special case you are interested in, with the support of $f$ being in $\left(0,L\right)$,
$$
\Phi(x)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx'g_2(x,x')f(x')
$$
is correct as well, simply because for $x'$ outside $\left(0,L\right)$ we have
$$
f(x') g_1(x,x') = 0 = f(x') g_2(x,x') = f(x') g_3(x,x')\,.
$$
(I.e. in the first formulation only the second integral contributes, the first and last just vanish.)
So your second option is correct, but other than for evaluation of the integral it feels a bit unnecessary to write it down that way.